# How to print a variable and a string in Python without a space between

Tags: python, printing

My code is the following:

```
a = 60

print(a, ": string of text")
```

this prints `"60 : string of text"`

I would like it to print `"60: String of text"` without the space after the `60` if that makes sense

any ideas?

Comment: `print("{}: string of text".format(a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to remove the space delimiter.  Fortunately `print()` only inserts a space between fields by default.  From the `print()` doc:

"*sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.*"

So my preferred way would be to use an empty string:

```
print(a, ": string of text", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

`print("{}: string of text".format(a))`

Answer (score 0):

if you use `print(... , ... , ...)` the `,` will always insert a space.

you can bypass that if you just concatenate them with

```
print(str(a) + ": string of text")
```

(the `str(..)` is needed because `a` is a number)
or you can use placeholders like so

```
print("%d: string of text" % a)
```

.. where `%d` stands for a digit. if you want a string, use `%s`

hope this helps :)