# Space in format while printing variables

Tags: python

Alright, so I have two variables and when I print them all is well, but there's a space when I run it.
I have tried end string after number but that messes up the count so I would like to have it print the variable number then count next to so number is set to = 1 and then when I run it, counts 10 11 12 etc. When it runs I get 1 0,   1 1,  1 2, etc

```
while count <= 100:
    print(number, count)
    count = count + 1
```

thanks in advance

Comment: similar to answers below, convert number and count to str and concatenate them: print(str(number)+str(count))

Comment: print has a keyword argument to define the separator:  print(number, count, sep='')  see answers for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a variable and a string in Python without a space between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807685/how-to-print-a-variable-and-a-string-in-python-without-a-space-between)

Answer (score 0):

By default the print statement prints each item in argument list with the space separator.

You could change the separator used in the print statement:

```
print(number, count, sep='')
```

You could also get string representations of the numbers and concatenate:

```
print(str(number) + str(count))
```

Or use a format expression:

```
print('%d%d' % (number, count))
```

Or the format method:

```
print('{}{}'.format(number, count))
```

These techniques are very useful when it comes to formatting all types of data into user-friendly strings.

Answer (score 0):

When you print integers with a print statement with a comma, it will space them for clarity.  If you want to "mush them together" into a representation without a space in them, you will have to convert them to a string and print that string, which is pretty straightforward by (1) converting them to strings and (2) joining them together like so:

```
In [33]: number = 5                                                             

In [34]: count = 0                                                              

In [35]: while count <=5: 
    ...:     temp = ''.join([str(number), str(count)]) 
    ...:     print(temp) 
    ...:     count += 1 
    ...:                                                                        
50
51
52
53
54
55
```